# C typedef for dereferencing a pointer to a fixed-size 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

If I have a pointer to a fixed-size 2D array, e.g.

```
char (*p)[4][4] = get_array();
```

is there any way to declare a variable `a` as

```
a = *p;
```

and have `a` properly be of type `char[4][4]`, so that I can use `a[i][j]` rather than `(*p)[i][j]`?

Comment: Depends on how you declare `a`, but no, C does not magically do this for you. Why a 2D array instead of an array of size `4*4`? Single-dimensional arrays are *significantly* easier to work with.

Comment: My biggest worry about the little code you show is the `get_array` function. What does it really return? Does it return a pointer to a local array of type `char [4][4]` (using e.g. `return &my_local_array`)?

Comment: You could work around that limitation by wrapping the array into a struct.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude get_array properly returns a heap-allocated array (this is in the middle of migrating some C code to rust, and I split out the part that created and populated a local array on the stack into a rust function that created and returned a pointer to the array). i just had to change all a[i][j] to (*p)[i][j] when i did it, which was annoying.

Comment: If you're not committed to C, C++ has [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) that are what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: i am unfortunately committed to C because that's what the original code is, though i hope to end up with it entirely in rust.

Comment: (but yes, i was indeed trying to get the equivalent of c++ references in c. i haven't done any pure c in ages, and am finding that it is a very different beast from 'just use the c portion of c++')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `p` is a pointer to an array of arrays of `4` characters, then `*p` must be an array of arrays of `4` characters (type `char [4][4]`). Unfortunately you can't really use that type for other variables (only when defining such an array), not even using a `typedef`. That's because you can't assign to arrays, only copy to them.

Luckily, as arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, an array of arrays of `4` characters will then decay to a pointer to an array of `4` characters.

That is, the expression `*p` is equivalent to `char (*)[4]`, which have to be the type of `a`:

```
char (*a)[4];
```

Comment: ... but on the other hand, no, if the type of `a` is in fact `char[4][4]`, as specified, then you cannot assign *anything* to `a` itself.  C does not have whole-array assignment.

Answer (score -1):

`a` is an array of type `char [4][4]`.

> is there any way to declare a variable a as
>
> `a = *p;`

No, you cannot initialize array like this and arrays are not assignable.

Instead, you should do:

```
memcpy (a, *p, sizeof(a));
```

and then you can use `a[i][j]`.